# DigitalOcean stop Node.js server running with nohup

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, putty, digital-ocean, nohup

I am running a Node.js server on a DigitalOcean droplet (with Ubuntu). I have worked out how to make it run when I'm not connected to it via Putty. However, just one issue: how do I stop it now?

I can see that control+C works when in the session, but what if I exit the session and come back? How will I stop the server then?

Also, will running it multiple times run multiple servers at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using a tool like `supervisord` (http://supervisord.org/) for your long-running processes.

But if you want to stop an already running process that you started with nohup then look up the process ID first (with `ps aux` and look/grep for your process) and then run `kill <<pid>>`.